# Is the set of all finite sets of powers of 2 countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Sort of confused on how to approach this question. I know that the set of powers of 2 is infinitely countable and the set of all sets of powers of 2 is the power set which isn't countable because it's bigger than the set. But here it's saying the power set is finite so would it be countable because its finite? Should I apply cantors diagonal theorem?

Comment: Count those of size 1, then those of size 2, those of size 3, etc. Finally take the union for all sizes 1,2,3,.... Take into account, or prove, that countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Another way could be to encode each set with a number in binary. List all powers of $2$: $1,2,1/2,4,1/4,...$. Then a sequence of $0$s and $1$s, like $(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,...)$ indicates with a 1 which power of $2$ will be in the set and with a zero which will not. Since the sets are finite, then the sequences of 0s and 1s end in a tail of 0s. Reading them from right to left there is a number natural number written in binary. In the example $10110$. This is a bijection from that set to the natural numbers.

Comment: What's going on with the tags?